# How to select available time and unavailable time(if atleast 30 minutes long) given a input date, room(optional)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with the following fields

```
ReservationID   int
ReservationDateFrom datetime
ReservationDateTo   datetime
ReservationRoom int
ReservationPurpose  varchar
ReservationDetailsID    int
```

I want to create an sp that selects available records and unavailable records(if atleast 30 minutes long) given Date(required), Room(optional), TimeFrom(optional), TimeTo(required if TimeFrom is not empty)
Example table

```
ReservationID ReservationDateFrom      ReservationDateTo        ReservationRoom     ReservationPurpose ReservationDetailsID
3002         2017-01-02 00:00:00.000    2017-01-02 02:00:00.000     14              qweqwe              3002
3003         2017-01-02 04:00:00.000    2017-01-02 05:00:00.000     14              qweqwe              3002
3004         2017-01-02 06:00:00.000    2017-01-02 08:00:00.000     14              eqweq               3002
3005         2017-01-02 08:30:00.000    2017-01-02 09:30:00.000     14              iuyiyi              3002
3006         2017-01-02 09:50:00.000    2017-01-03 11:00:00.000     14              qweqwe              3003
```

Desired results to select(display unavailable and available room and range)

```
ReservationID ReservationDateFrom      ReservationDateTo        ReservationRoom     ReservationPurpose ReservationDetailsID
3002         2017-01-02 00:00:00.000    2017-01-02 02:00:00.000     14              qweqwe              3002
3003         2017-01-02 04:00:00.000    2017-01-02 05:00:00.000     14              qweqwe              3002
3004         2017-01-02 06:00:00.000    2017-01-02 08:00:00.000     14              eqweq               3002
3005         2017-01-02 08:30:00.000    2017-01-02 09:30:00.000     14              iuyiyi              3002
3006         2017-01-02 09:50:00.000    2017-01-03 11:00:00.000     14              qweqwe              3003
             2017-01-02 02:00:00.000    2017-01-02 04:00:00.000     14                              
             2017-01-02 05:00:00.000    2017-01-02 06:00:00.000     14                              
             2017-01-02 08:00:00.000    2017-01-02 08:30:00.000     14              
             2017-01-02 11:00:00.000    2017-01-03 24:00:00.000     14
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the version of SQL Server you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the "unreserved" records using `lead()` (or `lag()`).  The basic idea is:

```
select ReservationID, ReservationDateFrom, ReservationDateTo,         ReservationRoom 
from reservations r
where . . .
union all
select NULL, ReservationDateTo,
       lead(ReservationDateFrom) over (partition by ReservationRoom),
       ReservationRoom
from reservations r
where . . .;
```

This doesn't produce exactly the output you have specified.  But I am unclear where some of the logic comes from, particularly the last row.

Comment: I am currently using sql server 2016 but I am looking for a solution that would work on lower level of sql server maybe atleast 2008 version.

Comment: The last row serves as a foreign key to another table.  Don't mind it. It should have nothing to do with the logic  of the query.